# How to find significance for Gini coefficient changes?

Tags: machine-learning, python, model, gini

I'm using the Gini coefficient to evaluate the performance of a model. Making some changes (feature selection, hyperparameter tuning, etc.) I created variant models with different Gini coefficients.

How can I prove that the improvement in the Gini coefficient is indeed statistically significant?

NB:
This question was [also](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/114955/how-to-find-significance-for-gini-coefficient-changes) asked in the Data Science StackExchange.

Comment: I question whether you need to. What's more important is whether the change is actually meaningful. A gini coefficient increase of 0.0000001 can be significant depending on how many data points you have, but that doesn't make it useful…

Comment: You are of course correct, but it will allow me to pick from multiple available models.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I'd probably recommend the "one SE" method. Choose the simplest (by whatever way you want to measure simplicity, such as the number of features or the penalty term if your model has that) model whose Gini index is within one standard error of the best observed Gini index.